# __init__.py not working correctly in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to make a sample package in python 2.7 just to clear my concepts whose structure looks like this:

```
    calculator/
    main.py
    operations/
        file1.py
        file2.py
        __init__.py
        new_operations/
            __init__.py
            file3.py
```

`main.py` content: (this file is present inside calculator folder)

```
from operations import power
print power(2,2)
```

`__init__.py` content: (this file is present inside operations folder)

```
from .file1 import add
from .file1 import sub
from .file2 import mul
from .file2 import div
```

`file1.py` content: (this file is present inside operations folder)

```
def add(a,b):
    return(a+b)

def sub(a,b):
    return(a-b)
```

`file2.py` content: (this file is present inside operations folder)

```
def mul(a,b):
    return(a*b)

def div(a,b):
    return(a/b)
```

`__init__.py` content: (this file is present inside new_operations folder)

```
from .file3 import power
```

`file3.py` content: (this file is present inside new_operations folder)

```
def power(a,b):
    return(a**b)
```

Now, when i run `main.py`, i got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mycodes\calculator\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from operations import power
ImportError: cannot import name power
```

Can anyone tell me, what mistake i am doing ? Help me.

Comment: But what in all this would lead you to think that `calculator.add` would work? Where do you think you are defining it?

Comment: `calculator` is not a package and has no `add`. `operations` is a package, and you could do `from operations import add`, but `calculator` isn't a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line in your "main.py" file:

```
from operations.new_operations import power
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an 'add' function in your calculator module. If you create an 'add' function, I would assume that the code would work.

maybe try doing this in the module calculator:

```
def add(num1,num2):
    print(num1+num2)
    return num1+num2;
```

If you don't want it to print while calculating, remove the print statement.

*Hope this helps!*